# Architecture error in integrating flurry ads 5.0.0 : undefined symbol for architecture i386

Tags: ios, flurry

I am integrating flurry ads. Previously ads are working in xcode 5.0.0 with flurry sdk 4.3.5..

But as I updated my xcode to 5.1.0 and flurry to 5.0.0, Ads are not working and showing an error,

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_crc32", referenced from:
      _unzReadCurrentFile in libFlurryAds_5.0.0.a(libFlurryAds.a-i386-master.o)
      _zipWriteInFileInZip in libFlurryAds_5.0.0.a(libFlurryAds.a-i386-master.o)
      -[ZipArchive addFileToZip:newname:] in libFlurryAds_5.0.0.a(libFlurryAds.a-i386-master.o)
  "_deflate", referenced from:
      _zipWriteInFileInZip in libFlurryAds_5.0.0.a(libFlurryAds.a-i386-master.o)
      _zipCloseFileInZipRaw in libFlurryAds_5.0.0.a(libFlurryAds.a-i386-master.o)
  "_deflateEnd", referenced from:
      _zipCloseFileInZipRaw in libFlurryAds_5.0.0.a(libFlurryAds.a-i386-master.o)
  "deflateInit2", referenced from:
      _zipOpenNewFileInZip3 in libFlurryAds_5.0.0.a(libFlurryAds.a-i386-master.o)
  "_get_crc_table", referenced from:
      _unzOpenCurrentFile3 in libFlurryAds_5.0.0.a(libFlurryAds.a-i386-master.o)
      _zipOpenNewFileInZip3 in libFlurryAds_5.0.0.a(libFlurryAds.a-i386-master.o)
  "_inflate", referenced from:
      _unzReadCurrentFile in libFlurryAds_5.0.0.a(libFlurryAds.a-i386-master.o)
  "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
      _unzCloseCurrentFile in libFlurryAds_5.0.0.a(libFlurryAds.a-i386-master.o)
  "inflateInit2", referenced from:
      _unzOpenCurrentFile3 in libFlurryAds_5.0.0.a(libFlurryAds.a-i386-master.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am resolve this error. Please help.

Also I have checked that flurry lib are showing in frameworks and also copied in bundle resources.

Comment: This probably means you are linking against a library that has only been compiled for ARM and you are trying to run it on the simulator. Try to plug in a device and run it there, let us know what happens!

Comment: same error occured, when try to run on the device.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Resolved the error, Adding "libz.dylib" library to framework in Target setting tabs.

Target setting -> Build Phases -> Link Binary with libraries.

Comment: flurry has not been added this to his documentation.

Comment: In new SDK 10.2 I didn't founded "libz.dylib" so i have added "libz.tbd". Its working thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are missing a required framework that flurryads has as a dependency.  Make sure you have 'SystemConfiguration', 'UIKit', 'Security' and 'CoreGraphics' added.